# Show that $ (\mathbf{1}_n-A)^{-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{l=0}^m A^l $ , how to approach that problem?

Tags: matrices, summation, inverse, nilpotence

> Let $ A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $ be nilpotent, i.e. there is a $ m \in \mathbb{N} $, such that  $ A^{m} $= 0

> Show that $$ (\mathbf{1}_n-A)^{-1} = \displaystyle \sum_{l=0}^m A^l $$

I am fully missing the propositions here to transform the LHS such that the RHS occurs.
Do anyone have an approach or a tip or the propositions themselves?

Comment: Multiply them??

Comment: What do you mean? Could you explain that? You have to know that I have really no clue right now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Two matrices are inverses if and only if they multiply to the identity. Can you find a way to simplify the expression
$$(I-A)\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^m A^\ell\right)$$
to show that it is the identity?

Comment: I just don't see it.. I don't know why I do not understand this.

Comment: @Operator, $(I-A)B=IB-AB=B-AB$